# When using BuildKit with Docker, how do I see the output of RUN commands?

Tags: docker, docker-buildkit

When building Docker images with `DOCKER_BUILDKIT=1`, there is a very cool progress indicator but no command output. How do I see the command output to debug my build?

Answer (score 182, accepted):

Have you tried `--progress=plain`?

Example:

- `Dockerfile`

  ```
  FROM alpine
  RUN ps aux
  ```
- `build` command:

  ```
  DOCKER_BUILDKIT=1 docker build --progress=plain -t test_buildkit .
  ```

Relative output:

```
#5 [2/2] RUN ps aux
#5       digest: sha256:e2e4ae1e7db9bc398cbcb5b0e93b137795913d2b626babb0f148a60017379d86
#5         name: "[2/2] RUN ps aux"
#5      started: 2019-04-19 09:02:58.922035874 +0000 UTC
#5 0.693 PID   USER     TIME  COMMAND
#5 0.693     1 root      0:00 ps aux
#5    completed: 2019-04-19 09:02:59.721490002 +0000 UTC
#5     duration: 799.454128ms
```

Also, check the very useful answer by [@Cocowalla](https://stackoverflow.com/users/25758/cocowalla) below about `BUILDKIT_PROGRESS=plain`

Comment: Also, make sure that the layer where print output is expected is not cached (`--no-cache `).  Otherwise, it won't print the expected output.

Comment: Do you know how to do this but only for one specific RUN line?

Comment: Hi @0xfede7c8, no I don't and I also couldn't find anything after a bit of search...

Comment: nope, doesn't work anymore.   

#18 [14/16] RUN ls /app/node_modules
#18 DONE 175.0s

Answer (score 136):

As well as using `--progress=plain` on the command line, you can also set an environment variable:

`BUILDKIT_PROGRESS=plain`

I find this particularly useful for CI builds, where I *always* want the full log.

Comment: Thank you! This is very useful when using docker-compose as you can't pass there --progress option.

Comment: We can also use `BUILDKIT_PROGRESS=plain` to ensure the `docker build` output is not colored and can be seen on a black foreground terminal.

Answer (score 4):

With [PR #2954](https://github.com/moby/buildkit/pull/2954) you can specify:

```bash
export NO_COLOR=1
```

There have also been changes in [recent versions](https://github.com/moby/buildkit/pull/2368) to make the defaults more readable.

You can pick your own color scheme with the [BUILDKIT_COLORS variable](https://github.com/docker/buildx/blob/v0.9.0-rc1/docs/guides/color-output.md), e.g.:

```bash
export BUILDKIT_COLORS=run=123,20,245:error=yellow:cancel=blue:warning=white
```

(Note, if the above doesn't work for you, then that PR likely hasn't made it into your Desktop install yet.)

Other options to solve this include switching to plain output with either the `--progress=plain` option or `export BUILDKIT_PROGRESS=plain`. Or you could disable buildkit with `export DOCKER_BUILDKIT=0`.