# How to review stdout of a successful "docker build"?

Tags: docker

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65580085/how-to-see-docker-build-run-command-stdout-docker-for-windows) fine question addresses how to *perform* a `docker build` with the stdout from `RUN` commands visible.

On the other hand, I have not been able to find a way to review the stdout from `RUN` commands from a standard `docker build` that has just run. Particularly if it's successful, since all that's left in the terminal is a list of the `Dockerfile` commands that were run. I find it really uncomfortable when I'm used to just "scrolling up" to review how things went.

Do I really need to delete the cache and re-run the 45 minute / 80GB process (in my case) with `--progress=plain` to not lose the output?

Answer (score -1):

With

```
docker ps
```

you can list running containers. From there you can get your container id of the container you want to see the logs.

After that you can simply say `docker logs <THE ID>` to see the logs. If you want to watch new incoming logs too, then say `docker logs -f <THE ID>`.

Comment: While that is true in principle, it has nothing to do with OP's question.