# Docker, Output is hidden

Tags: docker, terminal, dockerfile

Inside a dockerfile I had:

```
RUN python3 --version
```

While I see the command being executed when I build my docker image like this:

```
docker build -t dn ./
```

I'm not seeing an output.
So I though about changing it to:

```
RUN echo python3 --version
```

But that didn't solve my problem, any suggestions?

**Note:** I don't want all commands to show output in terminal only the ones I specify.

Comment: Does the recommendation in [When using BuildKit with Docker, how do I see the output of RUN commands?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55756372/when-using-buildkit-with-docker-how-do-i-see-the-output-of-run-commands) (`docker build --progress=plain`) help?

Comment: Hi @DavidMaze, kindly see my output under Ben's answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try setting the environment variable `DOCKER_BUILDKIT=0` and then execute the docker build command again. `DOCKER_BUILDKIT=0 docker build -t dn ./`
as explained here https://makeoptim.com/en/tool/docker-build-not-output

Comment: Is there a more clean way of showing output to specific commands only rather than showing for all?

Comment: even though this doesn't answer my question I will accept as workaround..

Comment: sorry i didn't see the note at the end of the question.