# How to get a list of files that were copied, for debugging build issue

Tags: .net, docker, dockerfile

I am having an issue building my docker container.  It says that the package restore is failing because

> #16 0.907 MSBUILD : error MSB1009: Project file does not exist.

## Docker file

```
# copy everything
COPY . ./Src

RUN echo "hello world"
RUN ls .

# Restore nuget packages for this service
RUN dotnet restore ./Src/Servies/ReadyPublisher
```

Is their anyway to get an out put of an ls or a dir or something to see what it has  copied.

I tried

- Run dir .
- Run dir ./Src
- Run pwd
- Run ls -la
- Run ls .

Im out of ideas.  Is there a way of knowing what was copied in by the copy command.  The directory i am running the request

I can see my echo but no files.

```
=> CACHED [runtime 5/6] WORKDIR /app                                                                                                                                                           0.0s
 => CACHED [build 2/7] WORKDIR /svc                                                                                                                                                             0.0s
 => [build 3/7] COPY . ./Src                                                                                                                                                                    1.9s
 => [build 4/7] RUN echo "hello world"                                                                                                                                                          0.5s
 => [build 5/7] RUN ls .                                                                                                                                                                        0.5s
 => ERROR [build 6/7] RUN dotnet restore ./Src/Servies/ReadyPublisher/
```

## Update

Tried find doesn't seem to find it either.

RUN find . -type f -name "ReadyPublisher.csproj"

Comment: [When using BuildKit with Docker, how do I see the output of RUN commands?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55756372/when-using-buildkit-with-docker-how-do-i-see-the-output-of-run-commands) suggests `docker build --progress=plain`; is that enough for you?

Comment: Well thats an interesting command